# Digest Authentication using async-http-client

Tags: swift, header, swift-nio

I am trying to implement digest authentication using async-http-client on top of swiftNIO. Therefore I use a class which uses the HTTPClientResponseDelegate protocol. In this class in the

```
func didReceiveHead(task: HTTPClient.Task<Response>, _ head: HTTPResponseHead) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
```

I parse the first server response and I generate the hash for the response. Now I have to construct the Authorization header with my hash, conforming to the digest authentication. But how can I send it to the server again from my class? Must I make a new HTTPClient.Request or I can make a response with an header directly from my class?
Perhaps somebody can give me a tip how to achieve this using swiftNIO and async-http-client.

Thanks
Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid that at the moment you do need to make a new request from your delegate. Currently there is no way to automatically send a new request.